# Redirect to custom 404 html page in DjangoCMS

Tags: django, redirect, django-templates, django-cms

How can I redirect the user to my custom `404.html` page if he enters a wrong path ?

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext

import threading

def url_redirect(request):
    return render_to_response('blog.html', RequestContext(request))

def post_redirect(request):
    return render_to_response('post.html', RequestContext(request))

def privacy_redirect(request):
    return render_to_response('privacy.html', RequestContext(request))

def terms_conditions_redirect(request):
    return render_to_response('terms.html', RequestContext(request))

def page_404(request):
    return render_to_response('404.html', RequestContext(request))
```

**urls.py:**

```
from __future__ import print_function
from cms.sitemaps import CMSSitemap
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
    url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),

    url(r'^blog', "website.views.url_redirect", name="url-redirect"),
    url(r'^post', "website.views.post_redirect", name="post-redirect"),
    url(r'^privacy', "website.views.privacy_redirect", name="privacy-redirect"),
    url(r'^terms', "website.views.terms_conditions_redirect", name="terms_conditions-redirect"),
    url(r'^404', "website.views.page_404", name="page_404"),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)

# This is only needed when using runserver.
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        ) + staticfiles_urlpatterns() + urlpatterns
```

I also have `TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True` and `DEBUG = False` in my `settings.py` file. Any help, please ?

Also, can you guys tell me if those methods from `views.py` are ok or if they could be rewritten in a better way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add 404.html near base.html (main folder templates)
and when there is an error 404 , Django itself take your 404 page

in settings.py

```
DEBUG = False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['yourweb.com']
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But the URL is not changing to `mysite/en/404.html`. Instead it is just appending the path with my modification. Any ideas ?

Comment: 404s should never redirect, but just state that there is nothing found, that's it...you'll screw up your SEO efforts if you redirect...